# Recover Phantom Wallet from address and password but no recovery phrase

Tags: phantom-wallet

I have the address and password but lost my recovery phrase. Can I login to my wallet?

Comment: When you say password, do you mean the private key or do you mean the password you enter to unlock the Phantom extension?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The keys to your coins are in your wallet and you only need the password to decrypt your keys. However, since you lost your recovery phrase, it would be prudent to make a new wallet for which you do store the recovery phrase, and transfer your funds there. In case your computer gets hacked, locked, your hard-drive fails or your simply forget your password, you do need that recovery phrase.

In case you lose your password, see this thread, where I provided an answer that ungratefully got down-voted.
[Wallet Recovery with Password Protected Seed phrases](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6728/wallet-recovery-with-password-protected-seed-phrases/8449#8449)