# Wallet Recovery with Password Protected Seed phrases

Tags: wallet

Using the Solana CLI, how can I recover my wallet?

I have the wallet pubkey and the password/passphrase that protects the seed phrase, but not the seed phrase itself.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

you can not recover your wallet without the seedphrase or the private key. Everyone can see your public key, if anyone could recover it using this key people could easily access your funds.

If you have the seed phrase you can follow the instructions here:
https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-restore-a-keypair-from-a-mnemonic-phrase

If you have the private key you can use:
https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-restore-a-keypair-from-a-secret

Answer (score -2):

Try in the following order:

1. Recover from seed phrase if your have one
2. If you know the password and need to get the raw key, use this free community tool:
   https://github.com/vidorge/solflare-decrypt
   Note that it does not actually check if the password is correct, meaning you cannot use it to recover a wallet if you do not know the password in full.

Comment: Not getting why this answer gets vote downs while it is offering the solution to the problem. I mean WTF? As far as I know there is no other way unless you know exactly the password, in which case you can use
https://github.com/vidorge/solflare-decrypt

Please check or explain yourself before down-voting. There are actually people who have this problem and have been stuck for years now without a solution until someone like me put in their hours to create such a recovery tool.

Comment: Another example of a user who is unable to recover his wallet without a dedicated recovery tool:
https://www.reddit.com/r/solana/comments/npepou/comment/h8k5xwa/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button
Note that there is always a balance between security and recover-ability. A good project needs a balance to provide the best user experience, hence all major projects like Bitcoin and Ethereum have proper tools to recover lost wallets. Salano should be no different and does require recovery options as major crypto project.

Comment: @Jacob Creech, You marked that part of my answer where I mention I have a recovery tool as "Advertisement" and you deleted my post in the developer forum about the tool without providing any explanation. Are you trying to keep the community in the dark on purpose? It is relevant for the community to know there is way to recover their fund if they forgot their password. It is part of ecosystem development. All major crypto projects have recovery tools available, Solana should have those tools available as well, and that information should not be censored IMO.

Comment: if you follow the rules set out on Stackexchange you will do fine. Self promotion should follow https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion
On the forum, that's not the place for advertisement of any tool. It's for research, SIMD discussion, and governance. None of these are related to your tool.

Comment: @JacobCreech The part in your answer that I am missing is where the proper place would be to inform the Solana community about the existence of a proper recover tool? There must be a way for ecosystem developments like these right?
Regarding governance, as I created a thread regarding governance on the forum, to discuss how external devs can contribute. Unfortunately that thread got deleted, which I find puzzling because it is about governance of the project.